# Stuck at OS X Utilities while clean installing Yosemite

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery-hd

I decided to do a clean Yosemite install on my Macbook Pro 13 inch Mid-2012 . So I made a boot able USB from terminal. Then I booted from it and went into disk utility and erased my current Disk which was Macintosh HD. Then I closed disk utility and clicked install OS X. As soon as I double clicked it the continue button grayed out and nothing is happening. I can move around the cursor which means it hasn't hung. I rebooted to the boot able USB and again clicked it and again the button grayed out. I have been waiting now for about 10 to 15 minutes and nothing has happened yet. What should I do?

[image]

This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the install you created is faulty somehow, possibly either a bad file copy or a bad flash drive.

Things to try, in order:

1. Rebuild the install drive using the same method you used before, but on a new drive.
2. Use the built-in recovery options (hold <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>) to do the install. Then, upgrade to the latest version of OS X. By upgrading to the newer OSX, your recovery partition will be set to do a clean upgrade of El Capitan if you have to do it again.
3. If that doesn't work (say your recovery partition is trashed), there's the Internet Recovery option, which will actually reinstall the OS your mac shipped with.